# How not to allow input field value greater then other

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have  several dynamic fields inside which I have some values, the first field is `Total Amt` and other are some dynamic fields and then one more `Bal Amt` which is initially opposite to total amount.

suppose `Total Amt=500` then `Bal Amt=-500` in my dynamic field one field is there which will be there always i.e `tender Cash`

**So what I am trying to do is**

`Tender cash` can be greater then `Total Amount` like if Total Amount = 500 then Tender cash can be 550 and then Bal Amt automatically will be +50

But there are several other fields I want them to restrict when Total bal is 0 then it should not accept input or alert or console

Like if `Total Amt=500` `tender cash=500 || 550` then all other will not take any input

if `Total Amt=500` `tender cash 50` then other can take inputs til `bal Amt=0` once bal Amt=0 the other should not take input.

I am using computed property to calculation, I don't know how to do above things.

**Code**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "TC",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Tender Cash"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "CC",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Credit Card"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "Cp",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Coupn"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "ptm",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "PayTM"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "Cr",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Credit"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato"
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    balAmt() {
      // sum of inputs of paymentMode
      const sum = this.paymentMode.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.Amount || 0), 0);
      return sum - this.totalAmt;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Total Amt</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label>{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="mode.Amount">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Bal Amt</label>
    <input type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>
</div>
```

**I have to do this with Vue.js only**

[image: Check this image]

Comment: Question is unclear for me. Are you looking for the entire logic ? And what do u meant by it should not accept input or alert or console

Comment: I meant once The balance is 0 the the input field except @ArunprasanthKV Tender cash should not accept input, I am just looking for logic to start or any small other example related to my code.

Comment: I am not sure about the exact logic what you are looking for , its depends on your business logic . Anyway from your above comment you can do a simple if statement like if($("#idofbalancefiled").val()===0) {$("#idoftendorcash").prop('disabled', true)}

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I just not want my input fields to accept value greater then Bal Amt. that's it

Comment: ok , try somethign like this $(".classnameofyourfields" ).keyup(function() {

    if($( "#balamountid" ).val() > $(this).val())
    {
        $( "#balamountid" ).val()
    }
});

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV if I had to do this with Jquery then  I could have already did it, Here I Am using Vue.js for this

Comment: will u he able to use Javascript?? its just an html page right? then why cant u use Javascript ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV thats correct but just check my code I can put javascript in between the way you are telling me to do will need to change my whole concept

Comment: events handling is possible via vue. js also

Comment: @manishthakur You can use disabled attribute of input and assign its value dynamically i.e. :disabled="balAmt === 0". Let me know if this helps

Comment: @Himanshu can you help me with some code with my code, Because i have tried so many things and getting issues

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV could you please help me with some code as of my code, because I have tried so many things and the are not working

Comment: @manishthakur if you just want to keep some input fields disabled if the value of balAmt is zero just put :disabled="balAmt === 0" on those input fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this -

I have used **:disabled**

```
<input type="text" v-model="mode.Amount" :disabled="balAmt>=0 && mode.PAYMENTCODE!='TC'">
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "TC",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Tender Cash"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "CC",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Credit Card"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "Cp",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Coupn"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "ptm",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "PayTM"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "Cr",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Credit"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato"
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    balAmt() {
      // sum of inputs of paymentMode
      const sum = this.paymentMode.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.Amount || 0), 0);
      return sum - this.totalAmt;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Total Amt</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label>{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="mode.Amount" :disabled="balAmt>=0 && mode.PAYMENTCODE!='TC'">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Bal Amt</label>
    <input type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "TC",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Tender Cash"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "CC",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Credit Card"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "Cp",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Coupn"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "ptm",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "PayTM"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "Cr",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Credit"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato"
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    balAmt() {
      // sum of inputs of paymentMode
      const sum = this.paymentMode.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.Amount || 0), 0);
      return sum - this.totalAmt;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onKeyUp(evt) {
      if (this.balAmt > 0) {
        let id = evt.target.id
        if (id !== 'TC') {
          let paymentMode = this.paymentMode.find(mode => mode.PAYMENTCODE === id)
          paymentMode.Amount = ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <label>Total Amt</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label>{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input :id="mode.PAYMENTCODE" type="text" v-model="mode.Amount" @keyup="onKeyUp">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Bal Amt</label>
    <input type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are bugs in your code, here tender cash can be greater then bal amount but you are not allowing it, and also when I am pressing 1 in any other field and focusing out it is then taking tht value

Comment: Check the updated code and let me know what other points I have missed.

Comment: hey some times it is not working, as when I am giving tender cash more so balance is in positive the I am adding something in next input it is taking greater and when I am again typing in the next one then it is not taking and bot are setting to `''`, I think code in breaking somewhere

Comment: Please check the image I have posted

Comment: To be clear, when does the inputs to the fields (Credit Card, Coupn, PayTM, Credit, Swiggy, uber Eats, and Zomato) get restricted?

Comment: the cant be greater then bal amount if bal amt =50 then all (Credit Card, Coupn, PayTM, Credit, Swiggy, uber Eats, and Zomato) their sub can not be greater then balance amount, any how when i press key I am calculating Bal amount so thse amounts can not be greater then Bal amt

Comment: That doesn't make sense since `balAmt` is derived from getting the sum of the all amounts of all payment modes.

Comment: No bal amount = Total amt- (all amount) and tender cash can be greater then total amount but we can't type any input in any other field which makes bal amount greater then 0 except tender cash

Answer (score 0):

you could set display flex to the div that contains both label and input and then apply the css directives applied as below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      totalAmt: 500,
      paymentMode: [{
        "PAYMENTCODE": "TC",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Tender Cash"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "CC",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Credit Card"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "Cp",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Coupn"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "ptm",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "PayTM"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "Cr",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Credit"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "SW",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Swiggy"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "BB",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "uber Eats"
      }, {
        "PAYMENTCODE": "WE",
        "PAYMENTNAME": "Zomato"
      }]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    balAmt() {
      // sum of inputs of paymentMode
      const sum = this.paymentMode.reduce((a, b) => a + (+b.Amount || 0), 0);
      return sum - this.totalAmt;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.payment-mode {
  display: flex;
}
.payment-mode > * {
  flex: 1; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="payment-mode">
    <label class="payment-name">Total Amt</label>
    <input class="payment-field" type="text" v-model="totalAmt">
  </div>
  <div v-for="mode in paymentMode" :key="mode.PAYMENTCODE" class="payment-mode form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
    <label class="payment-name">{{mode.PAYMENTNAME}}</label>
    <input class="payment-field" type="text" v-model="mode.Amount">
  </div>
  <div class="payment-mode">
    <label class="payment-name">Bal Amtdasdsadsadsad</label>
    <input class="payment-field" type="text" :value="balAmt">
  </div>
</div>
```